# Clonezilla not enough free memory

Tags: clonezilla

I have cloned an 1.2TB drive using clonezilla and put it on the NFS share. My friend is trying to use that image and burn it on his drive (6.4 TB one). After confirming everything and when we were hoping to see progress bars we have received and error "there is not enough free memory, partclone suggests you should have 1089871111003596937 bytes memory". This is quite a lot of memory to be honest. Can anyone help us?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Memory usually refers to RAM, not disk space. You should probably look into whether you have enough memory (RAM) to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is more than a lot of memory.  Thats asking for an exabyte, which is...  LARGE.

You didnt detail the steps you took to do the clone, so its impossible to say what could be the issue.  Assuming you did, this appears to be a bug in Clonezilla.

I suggest you go to Clonezilla's forum and post there.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Clonezilla_live/thread/31f2495b03/

Comment: @Furjoza well there you go

Answer (score 0):

Updating clonezilla to newer version (20200703-focal) resolved all issues.